What's best way in an industrial device to indicate language name
In an device with a user interface where the operator can select different languages, what would be the most correct way to put Chinese (simplified)  vs Chinese (traditional).
The languages are shown written in the respective languages.
Mockup, brackets represent buttons.
So far the translator has propsed something like
   [English]   [Dansk]  [Svenska]
   [汉语]      [漢語]

But is it more correct to put
   [中文]      [漢語]

Or different wordings ?
It should be done to best respect regions and cultures.

The usual labels for "Chinese (simplified)" and "Chinese (traditional)" are, respectively:

[中文(简体)]

and

[中文(繁体)]


Just use 简 and 繁. That's what I have seen on a lot of websites.
If you want to use graphics instead of characters, the typical way is to use a PRC flag and a HKSAR flag.

Chose the other solution proposed since mobile phones also list the languages in similar ways. A flag is not ideal, since flags are often politically loaded in one way or other.
